# comparing 2 large unsorted CSV files based on 2 columns

Tags: java, python, shell, csv, awk

I am tasks with comparing 2 large unsorted `.csv` files based on column 1 and 3.
Each file contains about 200k records. For the output, I need to know which records based on column 1 and 3 exist in the first file but not the second file. The files are quoted comma separated value files. Column 3 needs to ignore case when comparing.

Example File1:

```
"id", "name", "email", "country"
"1233",  "jake", "jake@mailinator.com", "USA"
"2345", "alison", "Alison@mailinator.com", "Canada"
"3456", "jacob", "jacob@mailinator.com", "USA"
"5678", "natalia", "natalia@mailinator.com", "USA"
```

File 2

```
"id", "name", "email", "country"
"2345", "alison", "alison@mailinator.com", "Canada"
"3456", "jacob", "jacob@mailinator.com", "USA"
"5690", "lina", "lina@mailinator.com", "Canada"
```

desired Output file

```
"5678", "natalia", "natalia@mailinator.com", "USA"
```

Code examples would be very appreciated.

Comment: Which language and what have you done so far and what is the problem?

Comment: Why does the line `"1233",  "jake", "jake@mailinator.com", "USA"` does not appear in the output?

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried java, with HashMaps, and it was super slow.

Comment: brandizzi, you are correct, jake should show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
join -v 1 -i -t, -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5  <(awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f1.txt | sort) <(awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f2.txt | sort)
```

How it works:

1) I first create a composite key column, by joining column 1 and column3:

```
awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f1.txt
awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f2.txt
```

2) I sort both outputs:

```
awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f1.txt | sort 
awk -F, '{print $1":"$3","$0}' f2.txt | sort
```

3) I then use the `join` command to join on the first column (my composite key) and output the unpairable lines coming from file 1.

**Output:**

```
"1233",  "jake", "jake@mailinator.com", "USA"
"5678", "natalia", "natalia@mailinator.com", "USA"
```

Comment: +1 column 3 is supposed to be case insensitive, so just need `tolower($3)` instead.

Comment: the awk commands work like a charm, however join is complaining, 1) it says -i is not a valid option
using: 
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the files, load them up into 2 arrays (or maybe hashes), then loop the second file, array'ing each line.  If `array1[n]` and `array2[n]` are not in the current line's array, output as missing.  I would use Perl for this task.

Comment: The files are large. It may not be wise to load them into arrays.

Comment: Then for each line in the base file, search line by line in the second file.  Not as quick, but you won't run into mem issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\", \""}
     FNR == 1 {read++;}
     FNR !=1 {if (read==1) {store[$1","tolower($3)] = $0} if (read==2) {delete store[$1","tolower($3)]}}
     END {for (i in store) {print store[i]}}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
"1233",  "jake", "jake@mailinator.com", "USA"
"5678", "natalia", "natalia@mailinator.com", "USA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the file content into a in memory database e.g. [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and use a SQL selection with a join

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}; NR==FNR{a[tolower($1$3)]=++i;next} { if ( tolower($1$3) in a);else {print } }' file2 file1
```

output:

```
"1233",  "jake", "jake@mailinator.com", "USA"
"5678", "natalia", "natalia@mailinator.com", "USA"
```